# The best way to pass values between classes in C#

Tags: c#, class, get, set

First case:

- If I have a set/get method for a value inside the class **A**, I can
  set that value from the class **B** and use it inside **A**.

Second case:

- I can just pass the value in a traditional way like `Method(value);`

Please, explain me which way is better.
I appreciate your answers.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you have examples? It's hard to tell what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties (what you call the `set`/`get` method) are essentially a "syntax sugar" on top of regular C# methods. There will be no performance difference between using properties and using regular methods.

Generally, though, you should prefer properties to methods for readability, i.e. when they present an appropriate semantics to the readers of your class.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I'm glad there's no performance difference as I really prefer properties, they look simpler for me to use from many classes. Good luck and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Setters and Getters should be used for general properties of classes, used across several methods.

A parameter to a method call is appropriate for a variable tied to that one method (though possibly stored and used elsewhere, for instance if it is part of initialisation).

As always, do what looks best and works well in your context. If the using code feels awkward, look for another way. If it feels right, it's probably OK.

Comment: Thank you, good advice! However, sometimes even if it works, I'm not sure it's right.

Comment: What is "right" anyway? It must work, it should be readable and understandable, it may have to follow house style/coding standards. Beyond that, its your choice.

Comment: Well, it's all about the performance actually. The only thing I'm bothered about.

Comment: If that is your issue,you should say so in the question -- then the answers might be more relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of Object oriented programming is to have your data and operations together.
The goal is to reduce coupling between different kinds of objects so that we can re use the classes.
Never expose the data inside the class to the outside world but provide interfaces to do so